# Install DVWA On VirtualBox

Tags: security, virtualbox

I want to install Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA) on VirtualBox, so I downloaded the DVWA.iso and I'm following [this tutorial](https://itfellover.com/building-an-ethichal-hacking-lab-on-your-laptop-with-virtualbox-part-11-damn-vulnerable-web-application-dvwa/) for its installation.

At step 9, they say to choose internal network, but I don't really understand why (is it a security problem if I don't choose this option?). Because if I select internal network after I've got an IP like 10.0.something and when I try to connect from my computer (not the VM) to 10.0.something/login.php that doesn't work. But if I select bridge networking, I've got an IP like 192.168.something and it works.

Could you explain me why is it important to choose internal network, and why that doesn't work when I choose this?

Comment: You can check it here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

Comment: also take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/a/95026/199557

Comment: Ok, can you tell me if i'm wrong. By using host only, i can access to DVWA by using the host but the DVWA cant be access from outside. And if i choose Internal network, the only way to access is DVWA is by using an other VM which is configured in the same Internal Network too ? So the good way to install vulnerable machine on virtualbox (in order to learn security aspect) is to put them in internal network or Host Only ?

Comment: As you can read from VBox documentation (click help menu -- pdf will be opened), chapter 6.2: ">Internal networking< This can be used to create a different kind of software-based network which is visible to selected virtual machines, but not to applications running on the host or to the outside world." So yeah. It's a best choice

Comment: OK, thx you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Internal network on VirtualBox creates a network between boxes on the same host . I can't see the next steps of the tutorial you linked but my guess is that it will ask you to install Kali (or similar distro) on another box on that same host. This is what most people do.
Setting 'internal network' allows the 2 machines to talk to each other without any contact with the outside.

It is considered a security measure because the DVWA is a vulnerable machine so some people think that you shouldn't be giving access to internet to it, but I guess it's more about 'best practice' than a real security risk because in most cases firewalls, routers and ISP will prevent outside attackers to connect directly to that machine in any case.

Anyways, if you are using another computer on the same network to connect to DVWA you should be ok in using a 'bridged' connection on VirtualBox (this it will give to the DVWA an IP sitting on the same network of the host and of your computer). In NAT mode VirtualBox acts like a router, it may still be a good solution for you but not sure if the box is reachable from other computers as I think VB settings may affect this case.

If you are using instead the Host as a penetration testing machine, 'host only' should be good to allow the host and the VM to talk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put both of the machines on the NAT so that you can ping onto the dvwa from wherever you're doing the hacking from! so essentially both of the machines should be on NAT setting if the they're both on a virtual machine.